# how to skip(do not allow) image and video tag from string using php

Tags: php

i have use following code to skip image tag from string ,
how do i skip image and video both ??

The following code skip image tag.

use code:

```
$content = $row['Description'] ;// comes from database table

$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content); 

echo $content;
```

Comment: Is there a problem that prevents you from using the same technique to remove video/object tags?

Comment: not problem with same technique but i did not know the exact syntax to skip video,i also google for it,but not clear.

Comment: As @Sn0opy points out in his answer, all you need to do is repeat the same code and change the `img` to the `video` or `object` tag that you are using to display the content.  Without details on the content; we cannot tell which you should use.  Look at the output HTML and determine which action is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within one single `preg_replace()` (untested)

```
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>|<video[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);
```

Alternative which should definitely work, but doesn't look very nice

```
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content); 
$content = preg_replace("/<video[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);
```

**edit**

Maybe you should also disallow `<embed>`, wich is used to embed .swf files.